# Retrieving information from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to check if the session username matches the record in my database and if it does, I want to include a file.

This is my code

```
<?php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo $username;
include('connect.php');
mysqli_select_db($connect,"persons");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE sessionusername='$username'"; 

$r = mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));

$geez = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

if($geez)   
{
    include('check.php');

}

else
{
echo "error";   
}
?>
```

The session username does not match the record in my database, yet the file is being included. Why?

OH, I FOUND THE ISSUE. IT IS CONSIDERING MY USERNAME TO BE ROOT...BUT WHEN I SAY ECHO $_SESSION['USERNAME'] IT IS CRAIG@CRAIG.COM..WHY SO>

Comment: var_dump($geez) what it says?

Comment: array(6) { [0]=> string(4) "root" ["sessionusername"]=> string(4) "root"

Comment: the current session username is craig@craig.com

Comment: hey men the user exists in database. double check it

Comment: this code is unsafe and you should use PDO prepared statements!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo $username;
include('connect.php');
mysqli_select_db($connect,"persons");

$sql = "SELECT sessionusername FROM users WHERE sessionusername='$username'"; 

$r = mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));

$geez = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

if($geez["sessionusername"]==$username)   
{
    include('check.php');

}

else
{
echo "error";   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply testing whether the array `$geez` is empty or not. If the array has *anything* in it, you `if($geez)` will return true. To stop this behaviour, please see **ceteras**' answer, particularly this part:

```
if($geez["sessionusername"]==$username)   
{
    include('check.php');

}
```

I believe that's the only part that has changed.

Thanks,

James

Comment: i applied ceteras answer and now even if the username matches the username in the database, the file is not being included.

Comment: Insert this: echo "|".$geez["sessionusername"]."|"; before the if. What's the result?